# POST a JSTL Collection to a servlet and populate a String[] that needs double quotes

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

OK, I wasn't too clear in my initial post/question.

My issue is that I have a jsp page where a person can select several files to download (the servlet it posts to should zip them up and deliver as a download).

The jsp page keeps track of the files selected in a JSTL collection.

When the person hits the download button it creates a var to post the files selected to the servlet like this,

```
<input type="hidden" name="files" value='<c:forEach var="item" items="${list}">${item}.ssg, </c:forEach>'>
```

Which sends something like 'xyz, xyz, xyz' to the servlet and is assigned to String[] srcFiles.

BUT, the problem is that the String[] needs to be formatted like this with double quotes,

```
String[] srcFiles = {"xyz", "xyz", "xyz"}
```

Not like

```
String[] srcFiles = {xyz, xyz, xyz}
```

The zip portion doesn't iterate through the array properly and returns a 0 byte zip file.

If I manually fill in String[] srcFiles with several files using double quotes the whole thing functions as it should.

Sorry for not being clear on my initial post.

```
package com.share.memberarea.zip;

import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.zip.ZipEntry;
import java.util.zip.ZipOutputStream;
import java.util.*;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.ServletOutputStream;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
//import javax.servlet.http.*;

public class zipSSG extends HttpServlet {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -4814365525955498299L;

    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)

    throws ServletException, java.io.IOException {

        String dl = request.getParameter("download");

        if (dl != null) {   

        String zipFile = "/home/httpd/html/research-material/ssg/ssg.zip";
        String[] srcFiles = {request.getParameter("files")};
        String zipDir = "/home/httpd/html/research-material/ssg";

        try {

            // create byte buffer
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];

            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(zipFile);

            ZipOutputStream zos = new ZipOutputStream(fos);

            for (int i=0; i < srcFiles.length; i++) {

                File srcFile = new File(srcFiles[i]);

                FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(zipDir + "/" + srcFile);

                // begin writing a new ZIP entry, positions the stream to the start of the entry data
                zos.putNextEntry(new ZipEntry(srcFile.getName()));

                int length;

                while ((length = fis.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                    zos.write(buffer, 0, length);
                }

                zos.closeEntry();

                // close the InputStream 
                fis.close();

            }

            // close the ZipOutputStream
            zos.close();

        } // end try

        catch (IOException ioe) {
            System.out.println("Error creating zip file: " + ioe);
        }

        //

        String zipLoc = "ssg.zip";

        ServletOutputStream stream = null;
        InputStream in = null;

        try {
            stream = response.getOutputStream();
            File zip = new File(zipDir + "/" + zipLoc);

        response.setContentType("application/zip");
        response.addHeader("Content-Disposition", "Attachment; Filename=" + zipLoc);

        response.setContentLength( (int) zip.length() );


        in = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(zip));

        byte[  ] buf = new byte[8 * 1024];
        int bytesRead;

        while ((bytesRead = in.read(buf)) != -1) {
            stream.write(buf, 0, bytesRead);
        }

        } catch (IOException ioe) {

            throw new ServletException(ioe.getMessage());

        } finally {

            if (in != null) in.close(  );           
        }

        //

    } // end doGet 

    }

    public void Redirect(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException{
    response.sendRedirect("/memberarea/df-search.html");

    }

}
```

Comment: Sorry, but what is the question?

Comment: sorry, I clarified it I hope...late night when I posted this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I understand from your question you want to split your request value coming from JSP to String[] array which is basically your files list which to be included into your zip file.

You can directly convert your String `xyz,xyz,xyz` into `String[] srcFiles = ...` by using [String.split("regex")](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) as show below :

```
String fileStr = request.getParameter("files");
String[] srcFiles = fileStr.split(","); // your file name is separated by ',' (comma)
```

I hope this will help.

If this is not what you are looking let me know.

Comment: You're on the right track. I clarified my question above, the issue is with iterating through the array and the need for double quotes in it.  Check my question again, hopefully I did a better job of explaining it.  Thanks for trying to help me.

Comment: Yup, I reconstructed the post var and used your suggestion, it worked.  Thank you very much!